# Dynamic files include on Visual Studio build process

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-automation

I got a question about the build process on VS.
I have a DLL Project with 3 .cs files inside. I would like to be able to define which files to include in the compilation process. So I can build a dll file only with file1.cs. Or file2.cs. Or file1.cs and file3.cs.

For now, the only way I know, is to create as many proj file I need and choose manually which one to build.

I would like to know if there are any other way to do it, maybe in the prebuild event you can redefine the files included or not. Maybe some addin exists ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditionally include files in a project file by putting a condition on the itemgroup.
Open up your csproj in a text editor:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" Condition="$(BuildtypeA)!='True'" />
    <Compile Include="Program1.cs" Condition="$(BuildtypeA)!='True'" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Use whatever condition you like- in this case BuildtypeA. You can pass this in as aproperty on the commandline to msbuild. (or my creating.modifying a build configuration)

You can also use wild cards on a given folder and it will include in the project file what ever is at a given location.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\dynamiccontent\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

No add-in required.

Comment: Very nice!   I completely forgot about setting conditions.

Comment: Ho I never used the Condition attribute, it's a nice one. Very powerful for what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why you couldn't just compiles the project with all 3 files all the time,  but if you really need to do something like this,  you can check out the MSBuild extensions.   They support the ability to manipulate an Xml document (which is what a csproj file is)  and you can dynamically add/remove the reference to the files as needed.   Let me know if you need an example of doing something like that.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but actually this is the solution I'm using. I don't know if there are any better solutions or better ways to do it. I would like to have differents builds to mix smallest size and only necessary functionnalities.

Comment: Check the answer by James above; that might be a better solution for you.